# How to fit a column as a function of another column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-fitting

For example, I have a dataframe (df) and the Target column is `df['Z']`.  I have two other columns, `df['X'] and df['Y']`. I have received all this data from the real-world data collection.

How can I make an equation Z as the following functions in python: (i.e. fit Z as a function of X and Y)

```
>  1. Z = f(X)
>  2. Z = f(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you do that:

```
def function(x, y):
   return x+y+4 # Obviously the function can be more complex
df["Z"] = function(df["A"], df["B"])
```

#### Example

```
data = {'A': [x for x in range(5)], 'B': [x for x in range(6,11)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def function(x,y):
   return x+y+4
df["Z"] = function(df["A"], df["B"])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A   B   Z
0  0   6  10
1  1   7  12
2  2   8  14
3  3   9  16
4  4  10  18
```